# Restored files which were deliberately deleted

Tags: windows-10

A friend of mine gave me external hard drive and he deleted some personal files (using his computer) before he gave it to me. Few days after I plugged the HD in my PC, I saw several deleted files in my recycle bin (my PC) which originate from the HD. Thinking I accidentally deleted the files, I restored the files from my recycle bin. Can files deleted using other PC show in recycle bin of another PC? And yes, the restored files are actually timestamped at the time I restored from my PC. I am using Windows 10.
Thank you,
Amanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is generally how `.Trashes` works across many operating systems, though Windows calls this `recycle.bin` it follows similar rules.

If you delete a file, all that happens is the pointer to the file is reset to be inside `Trash`. The file on disk doesn't move at all.

What you see as a convenient single Recycle Bin on your desktop on Windows, or Trash or Bin on Mac or nix is not just one location, it is a smart amalgum of all `.Trash` folders currently present from all mounted partitions. You will have one `.Trash` for each user, at least one for the system itself & one for each mounted drive.
The Recycle Bin just presents them to the user as if they were a single location. Which you can see will depend on your permissions - you won't see another user's [on the same computer] Trash in your recycle bin for instance. However, permissions for removable drives can be very different, especially if they are formatted FAT of any sort, because FAT cannot hold proper permissions, so they're generally presented as accessible by everyone.

Thus, by accident or intention, if you delete a file on a removable drive then mount that drive on another computer, those trashed files will re-appear, as if by magic, on the other computer.

Comment: Thank you so much Tetsujin

Answer (score 0):

When transferring a disk from one computer to another, it will come with
its recycle bin.

The $RECYCLE.BIN folder on the root of the disk is a hidden system
folder that contains the files that were deleted on that disk.

The Recycle Bin applet will give you the list of all the files that
are found in all the recycle bins of all the disks.
Which is what happened to you.

Comment: Thank you so much